# Interactivity not working with matplotlib TkAgg backend

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am trying to get an interactive plotting using matplotlib. The plot is rendered, but the interaction is  not working. This

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.figure()
data = np.random.rand(10)
plt.plot(data)

def onclick(event):
    plt.cla()
    plt.plot(data)
    print('click event')
    plt.gca().set_title('Event at pixels {},{} \nand data {},{}'.format(event.x, event.y, event.xdata, event.ydata))

plt.gcf().canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)
plt.show()
```

This produces the figure, but when when I am not sure, if the issue is because of the 'button_press_event' or the backend 'TkAgg'.

```
matplotlib.__version__
'3.1.1'

mpl.get_backend()
'TkAgg'

tkinter.TkVersion
Out[8]: 8.6
```

I also tried using `Qt5Agg` backend, still did not succeed with getting interactivity working.

```
matplotlib.get_backend()
'Qt5Agg'

from PyQt5.QtCore import QT_VERSION_STR
QT_VERSION_STR
'5.13.2'

from PyQt5.Qt import PYQT_VERSION_STR
PYQT_VERSION_STR
'5.13.2'

from sip import SIP_VERSION_STR
SIP_VERSION_STR
'5.0.0'
```

Comment: I guess you forgot to redraw the canvas after making changes to it, `plt.gcf().canvas.draw_idle()`.

Comment: Still not working. I am not even getting the print message on mouse click event.

Comment: Oh, that means something else is entirely wrong. How exactly do you run this code?

Comment: I am using pycharm editor on windows10

Comment: Mhh, not sure what goes wrong in PyCharm, but I suppose outside of it it would work right?

Comment: Not sure.I'll try and let you know

Comment: It's the same issue when I execute from python console from windows terminal (cmd) also. I believe it is an issue with TkAgg backend. Maybe it needs some additional libraries or settings to enable interaction.

Comment: No additional libraries would be needed, apart from Tkinter and matplotlib.

Comment: I have matplotlib 3.1.1 and Tkinter version 8.6 running, but still not able to make this code interactive. Not sure what I am missing here.

Comment: Just to make sure, if you prepend your code with `import matplotlib; matplotlib.use("Qt5Agg")`, would it change anything?

Comment: I am getting importerror --> `ImportError: Failed to import any qt binding`

Comment: Ok, that's because you haven't got PyQt installed. You could do that, and then see if it changes anything.

Comment: Even with using `Qt5Agg` it is not working. So, I don't think it is an issue with `TkAgg` or `Qt5Agg` backend. The same works with JupyterNotebooks. I suppose the issue is somewhere else.

Comment: Right, if it doesn't work with two different backends, the backend cannot be the cause. You can of cause make your case as reproducible as possible by stating how you installed python/matplotlib, and then hope that someone else can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hopefully!! I have added the details